# Heroku App not Found

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm in the MyAppName directory.

```
heroku config
| App not found
```

I have to type

```
heroku config --app MyAppName
MONGOLAB_URI: mongodb://herokuapp1234:abcd1234.mongolab.com:49538:heroku_app1234
PATH: bin:node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

How do I set heroku config to detect my app without using --app?

I'm guessing this is the reason why my app.js can't use the process.env.MONGOLAB_URI and I get an application error when I deploy to Heroku.

Comment: Are you running the Toolbelt from the top level of your app directory?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't think so? I just do git push staging-heroku staging:master. And I added MongoLabs from the heroku website instead of through the command line.

Comment: What does "from the top level of your app directory" mean? Thanks for your help Vidya :)

Comment: Like on your local machine there is a directory that is the root of your project. Try navigating there in the command line and running the Toolbelt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the **Heroku toolbelt** in your app directory.